# how to stop refreshing parent page while child window open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

when i click link to open child window, parent page refresh automatically. how can i stop it?

parent page should not refresh while open child window. how to do this? please help me.

my code is as below given:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>login</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

<script type="text/javascript">
var popup;
function ShowPopup(url) {
if(popup)
    {
     popup.close();
     }
    popup = window.open(url, "self", "toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,location=no,statusbar=no,menubar=no,resizable=0,width=300,height=350,left = 0,top = 0");
        popup.focus();
 }
</script>

</head>

<body>
<a href="" onclick="ShowPopup('popup_login.asp')" style="color: #1686CC;">Sign In / Register</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Set a `flag` once child window is open and unset it once its closed. In `ShowPopup` use `event.preventdefault()` if child window is open!

Comment: @rayon dabre, please help how to do that. my code is as above.

Comment: @rayon dabre, the window.event object is only defined in IE. It would require some rewriting to make it cross-browser.

Answer (score 13):

Your page refreshes because not only is your function called, but also the 
hyperlink indicated by the `a` tag is executed. So you have two things happening 
at the same time:

- the hyperlink itself navigates to whatever is in the `href` attribute, 
  even if it is empty. If `href` is empty it means: reload this page.
- the `onclick` event handler also does something (opening a popup), but it 
  does currently not cancel the first effect.

In a first reaction one might just remove the offending `href` 
attribute. This solves the problem, but introduces another: you lose all the nice
styling on the displayed hyperlink text (like underline, color, changing cursor, tab order, ...), 
which is generally not what you want.

Here are some more convenient solutions:

**Let the `onclick` event handler return `false`**

Returning `false` will cancel the anchor's default behaviour and the content of the `href` attribute will be ignored:

```
onclick="ShowPopup('popup_login.asp'); return false;"
```

If you care about browsers that have no javascript support (or have it disabled), then put
a meaningful fall-back `url` in the `href` attribute, like:

```
href="javascript_is_required.html"
```

**Use `event.preventDefault`**

This is an alternative to `return false`. It has the advantage that you can make it 
execute as the first instruction, so that if a run-time error occurs in the other code
it will already have done it's job:

```
onclick="event.preventDefault();ShowPopup('popup_login.asp');"
```

Note that this `event` object is defined by all browsers in the context of event attributes,
and is to be distinguished from the `window.event` object, which is not supported by
all browsers.

**Use hash notation in `href`**

Give the anchor a name
and then reference that name in the `href` attribute. This way
the anchor will navigate itself into view, which 
it usually already is when the user clicked it:

```
name="loginlink" href="#loginlink"
```

You will often see the shorter variation `href="#"`, but this will scroll the page to the top
when clicked, which might be OK if you know for sure the page is not scrolled down.
Still, the use of "#" has a side-effect: when clicked the `url` changes and the 
previous `url` is put on the browser's history stack. So if after clicking the link you press the back button, 
you stay on the page. This may be undesired.

**Use the `javascript:` protocol to do nothing**

```
href="javascript:"
```

This will make the hyperlink execute any javascript following the colon, and since there
is none there, nothing will happen. The browser history is not modified. There are variations
to this method, like `javascript: return false;` or `javascript: void(0);`

**Use the `javascript:` protocol to handle the `click` event**

With this solution you no longer use the `onclick` attribute. Instead you move the code
to the `href` attribute:

```
href="javascript: ShowPopup('popup_login.asp');"
```

**Separation of lay-out and code**

The original code and all the above solutions still have an issue that many developers
do not like: `HTML` is mixed with `javascript` code. It is better to separate these two.

This can be done as follows:

```
<a href="javascript_is_required.html" id="loginLink"
   title="Click here to log on"> ... </a>
...
<script>
    document.getElementById('mylink').onclick = function(e) {
        e = e || event; // cross-browser way to get event object
        e.preventDefault(); // cancel the default click behaviour
        ShowPopup('popup_login.asp'); // your custom code comes here
        return false; // cancel the default click behaviour
    };
</script>
```

A few will say this also
has a down-side: it is harder to identify the code that executes on a click. 
The above code will attach the event handler to the `click` event of the mylink
element. Make sure to have it execute only after the document has loaded. 
The event handler cancels the default click
behaviour in two ways. Choose the one you prefer, or both if you want. As it is 
cancelled, the navigation to the `href` attribute value is never executed. The first 
line deals with browser specifics as older IE browsers do not pass the event object 
as an argument to the event handler, but expose a global `event` object instead.

If you don't have to support pre-IE9 browsers, you can improve more by using
`addEventListener('click', myfunction);` instead of `onclick = myfunction;` in the 
above code. This has many advantages: more event handlers can be attached to the same
event, and you can also remove them one by one. `jQuery` offers good cross browser support
for this with [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

There are several variations on the above solutions, all with their 
benefits and downsides. You could even step away from using an anchor for this purpose
and use another element instead with styling added to it.

Comment: @trincot, thanks! work great. after adding your solution in onclick, parent is not refreshing. i accept your solution as answer.

Comment: "onclick event handler return false", worked for me!

Answer (score 6):

Write return `false();` after the `window.open()` JS method.

In case the above snippet is not working, change the default `<button>` tag to normal `<input>` tag with `type="button"`. This will solve the problem.

Below is the code snippet:

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
  function tagedlist() { 
    window.open("http://w3schools.com","mywindow","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=1000,height=1000");
    return false;           
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding `type="button"` in `<button>` tag worked. I know it's redundant but it worked!

From this:

```
<button id="btnDeleteRequest" class="btn btn-default"  accesskey="D" onclick="ExecuteCommand('DeleteRequest',this);">
```

To this:

```
<button id="btnDeleteRequest" class="btn btn-default" type="button" accesskey="D" onclick="ExecuteCommand('DeleteRequest',this);">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had button something like this
html:

```
<button onclick="captcha()" >Verify Human</button>
```

js:

```
function captcha(){
  window.open(link,name,"width=800, height=600");
  return false;
}
```

After adding type="button" in html content it worked

```
<button onclick="captcha()" type="button">Verify Human</button>
```

I know its redundant but it works ;)

Also thanks to @sojim