# Window.open used with <a> <commandLink> reloads the screen and jquery object is returned as 0

Tags: window.open

I am working on prime faces and using "a onclick="window.open('url')""

```html
< a onclick=window.open('url')/>
```

to open a certain link in the same window I have used jquery on the click of the link which will open the contents of that link. But what happens is when the link is clicked, the contents are shown for a fraction of seconds then the page gets reloads and everything goes blank. I have used suggestions from [how to stop refreshing parent page while child window open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33460296/how-to-stop-refreshing-parent-page-while-child-window-open) this page which I guess is the best answer but somehow my problem is not solved.
Also in the console section the jquery object is returned as 0 when I try to hit the jQuery method through it.
Note:
 The jquery is used only for visibility of css and does not contain any code.

Comment: These is nothing query or PrimeFaces related in your code. Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates their influence in the problem or remove the tags. Cheers

Comment: hei.. i was actually using <p:commandLink> before <a>.. and my whole code is in primefaces.

Comment: There is a link in my previous comment. Read it and improve your question then. Otherwise the question is NOT PrimeFaces related and the tag will be removed. And as the code is no-one with PF knowledge can help you

Answer (score 0):

I would advise moving this to jQuery or JavaScript.

For example:

```
$(function() {
  $("a.new-window").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open($(this).attr("href"));
  });
});
```

With HTML Like:

```
<a href="http://www.googloe.com/" id="link-1" class="new-window">Open Link</a>
```

Hope that helps.