# How to use window.open(url,"_blank") without changing calling application's url?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angular-ui-router, window.open

This is my js **window.open()** code.

```
var url = "https://www.google.com"
window.open(url, "_blank", "menubar=no,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes,width=640,height=480", false);
```

It opens a new browser window with the "url" as expected.
But the issue is that, it also changes the current url in my main web application.

For example before my **window.open()** call if I was on this url:

```
https://example.com/#!/projects/56asda/view
```

After the call the url redirects to this:

```
https://example.com/#!/
```

How can this issue be prevented? I have not found any solution for this on the internet.
I am using angularjs 1.0 for my frontend.

Please refrain from answering that "_blank" should work etc.

Any help will be invaluable.

Comment: Have you tried to use AngularJS's $window service rather than the native window object? Also, which router are you using? ng-router or ui-router?

Comment: we use ui-router.

Comment: Ah - you're using a relative URL. Add `https://` to the front of your URL. That should do it.

Comment: I have updated my question. I do use https://

Comment: How are you calling this code from your view? Is it attached to an anchor tag (i.e. `<a href...>`)?

Comment: No. We have a threejs app running inside a html <canvas? where all this window.open() stuff is happening in the background. No <a href> tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to stop refreshing parent page while child window open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33460296/how-to-stop-refreshing-parent-page-while-child-window-open).

Answer (score -1):

I have tried to duplicate your issue but I have found no issues while executing the code which would mean your issue might be related to your web server settings.

Anyways, have you tried calling it like this:

```
var url = "https://yourlink.here";
window.open(url, "_blank");
```

Without anything like "menubar=no" or other arguments?

If you haven't, I suggest you do and if that works, just add the arguments one by one to check which one contains the error.